# Illegal start of type and how to make a loop in a value returning method

Tags: java, methods

This method is supposed to pass the values 1-10 as arguments in a loop and display the return value which is the distance an object has fallen in 1-10 seconds. I'm getting the error illegal start of type, I don't know if it matters that I'm using int for the seconds and double for the distance, and I don't know how to loop it when second1 changes to second2 and so on.

```
         public class showDistance
    {

            public static void main(String[]args)   

        {
            showDistance(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

            public static int showDistance(int second1, int second2, int second3, 
            int second4, int second5, 

int second6,
        int second7, int second8, int second9,
        int second10)
        {   
            double distance; //to hold the distance
            distance = 0.5(9.8)(second1)(second1)
            return distance;
            System.out.println("The distance the object has fallen after " + second1 + 
                " second is " + distance + "m.")
        }

        {   
            double distance; //to hold the distance
            distance = 0.5(9.8)(second2)(second2)
            return distance;
            System.out.println("The distance the object has fallen after " + second2 + 
                " seconds is " + distance + "m.")
        }

        {   
            double distance; //to hold the distance
            distance = 0.5(9.8)(second3)(second3)
            return distance;
            System.out.println("The distance the object has fallen after " + second3 + 
                " seconds is " + distance + "m.")
        }

        {   
            double distance; //to hold the distance
            distance = 0.5(9.8)(second4)(second4)
            return distance;
            System.out.println("The distance the object has fallen after " + second4 + 
                " seconds is " + distance + "m.")
        }

        {   
            double distance; //to hold the distance
            distance = 0.5(9.8)(second5)(second5)
            return distance;
            System.out.println("The distance the object has fallen after " + second5 + 
                " seconds is " + distance + "m.")
        }

        {   
            double distance; //to hold the distance
            distance = 0.5(9.8)(second6)(second6)
            return distance;
            System.out.println("The distance the object has fallen after " + second6 + 
                " seconds is " + distance + "m.")
        }

        {   
            double distance; //to hold the distance
            distance = 0.5(9.8)(second7)(second7)
            return distance;
            System.out.println("The distance the object has fallen after " + second7 + 
                " seconds is " + distance + "m.")
        }

        {   
            double distance; //to hold the distance
            distance = 0.5(9.8)(second8)(second8)
            return distance;
            System.out.println("The distance the object has fallen after " + second8 + 
                " seconds is " + distance + "m.")
        }

        {   
            double distance; //to hold the distance
            distance = 0.5(9.8)(second9)(second9)
            return distance;
            System.out.println("The distance the object has fallen after " + second9 + 
                " seconds is " + distance + "m.")
        }

        {   
            double distance; //to hold the distance
            distance = 0.5(9.8)(second10)(second10)
            return distance;
            System.out.println("The distance the object has fallen after " + second10 + 
                " seconds is " + distance + "m.")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this Java? In that case I think you need to read a few tutorials on Java program structure.

Comment: Yes, have started reading one, and realised there was no main method in my code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow what you want to achieve but assuming you want to show the distance something has fallen at each of the times passed to a function you could do something like:

```
public class FallDistance {
    private static final double GRAVITY = 9.81;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        showDistances(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    }
    private static void showDistances(int... times) {
        for (int time : times) {
            System.out.println(String.format("The distance the object has fallen after %d seconds is %f", time, distanceAfterTime(time)));
        }
    }
    private static double distanceAfterTime(int seconds) {
        return 0.5 * GRAVITY * seconds * seconds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to square those seconds: ``return 0.5 * GRAVITY * seconds * seconds;``

Answer (score 0):

The illegal start of statement came for the second open bracket {.
The first } bracket close your function.

And you say `public static int` and you will give a double as return value. The Compiler will give you an error.

```
public static double(int[] sec){ // a array for you 10 values
      for(int i = 0; i < sec.length; i++){
           double distance = 0.0;
           //distance = 0.5(9.8)(sec[i])(sec[i]) i don't understand your intention
           // i think you mean this
           distance = 0.5*9.8*(double)sec[i]*(double)sec[i];
      }
      return distance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I wasn't really sure how I was supposed to go about solving the problem and the two answers already posted have elements of what I wanted. I knew I was probably supposed to call a method, and we've been doing arrays, so that was a cool idea too. I guess there are many ways to skin a cat(no offence cat lovers). I found this answer and adapted it slightly on "dream in code" under falling distance which is the name of the question in Gaddis "Starting out in Java".

```
public class Practice
{
    public static void main (String [] args)  
    {  
        double fallingTime;  
        for(int x=1;x<11;x++)  
        {  
            System.out.println("The distance after " + x + " second/s is " + fallingDistance(x) + "m.");  
        }  
    }  
    public static double fallingDistance(double fallingTime)  
    {  
        double a=0.5, g=9.8;//0.5=1/2  
        double d=a*g*fallingTime*fallingTime;   
        return d;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add brackets to everything. `d = a * g * fallingTime * fallingTime` is at least as clear and just as correct. Same with `return d`.